# Keyboard shortcut for documentation of a function in VS Code Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

[This can be done if i hover the cursor in the (), but i prefer to use keyboard.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFFhF.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

VS Code indeed provides such keyboard shortcuts. Click the code you want to see documentation then press `Ctrl+K Ctrl+I` to show hover:

[image]

More keybindings please click **Manage--> keyboard Shortcuts**.